# Is there a Surround With for aptana studio plugin?

Tags: html, eclipse, code-snippets, aptana3, code-assist

Is there some way to get "surround with" in the Aptana perspective in Eclipse like you have in the Java perspective.  I would love to be able to surround text with html tags like eg: `<div></div>` with a keyboard shortcut.  Is there some way of doing that with the snippets rubles?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AutoHotKey, which has the added benefit of being available across all apps. I have a script which launches a 'surround' menu when I select some text and press CTRL+SHIFT+C

To use it, install AutoHotKey, and create a new .txt file with the following code, and replace the extension with .ahk

http://pastebin.com/48ipiXsG

At the top of the file you'll find a number of groups of items, in the following format

```
<h1>~<h1>@@</h1>
```

the ~ character divides the name of the function and the function content. The bit before ~ is what appears on your menu, and after the ~ is the code. @@ represents where your selected text will go. So if you select the text 'AutoHotKey' and press CTRL+SHIFT+C, and then select `<h1>` from the menu, it'll replace the with `<h1>AutoHotKey</h1>`

There are several menus in the script, set up to launch based on what app you press CTRL+SHIFT+C in. For example, I get different shortcuts if I'm in Visual Studio than if I'm in SQL Server. You can modify these easily enough, but the generic menu should work fine for you. Feel free to chop and change but you have to leave GENERIC at the top of the script.

PS: I use this script everyday, and there is one small bug. The script saves whatever you have in the clipboard in a variable, and then writes it back to the clipboard when it's done. Sometimes, instead of surrounding text it replaces it with whatever you had in the clipboard. This is easily undone with CTRL-Z and usually works the second time you try it. I've never been able to figure out what causes this, maybe some autohotkey heads can help out?

PPS : This script is based on some other scripts from the AHK forums, including this one 
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/FavoriteFolders.htm
So you may find comments that don't make sense. I've seen a few references to the middle click, as the script above uses the middle mouse button instead of CTRL+SHIFT+C.